# Grouping of data fetched from firestore using Angularfire2

Tags: angular, database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Functionality:**

I have a Angular project for which I have to generate a graph showing invoiceDate vs saleAmount. The data is fetched from the invoice collection.

```
var invoiceRef = this.afs.collection<Invoice>('invoices', 
    ref=> ref.orderBy('creationDate','desc'));
```

Here I am getting the saleAmount and invoiceDate for each invoice.

**Issue**

How to count the saleAmount for each invoice Date?

In traditional SQL you would write something like

```
SELECT COUNT(saleAmount) FROM invoice GROUP BY invoiceDate;
```

How to do the same using angularfire queries for  firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it can be done directly from a firestore query, but you can implement a function that does this after you get the data (or before, with [cloud functions](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions)).

It could look like this:

```
const groupedInovices = {};
invocies.forEach((inovice) => {
      groupedInovices[invoice.date] = groupedInovices[invoice.date] ? groupedInovices[invoice.date]++ : 1;
    });
```

You will end up with an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "05/30/2019": 20
  "05/29/2019: 13
}
```

Comment: I thought the same. I also ended up doing something similar. Thanks for the confirmation though.